# what is the difference between #include in C language and import statement in java language?

Tags: java, c

*#include*
*import*
These two keywords imparts the same meaning in the respective languages they are used.But in one of my technical interview my interviewer asked me this question and when I was unable to answer he asked me to find out,as these two keywords have a major difference in terms of there action.

Comment: First of all these are different languages

Answer (score 1):

`#include` directive just copy / insert one file inside onother at the level of source code, i.e. before copilation.

Java's import statement (for package, class, or static member) arranges links at the level of compiler